# Better way to implement network thread than using a loader or AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, loader

The Loader class is depreciated and while overriding the methods for network call the callback function are not performing as aspected.

I've implemented the "implements LoaderCallbacks>"

```
       ConnectionManager connMgr =(ConnectionManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
           LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
           loaderManager.initLoader(CUSTOM_JSON_LOADER_ID, null, this);
       } else {
           View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
           loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Note that only the framework Loaders (`android.app.LoaderManager`, etc.) are deprecated, the Support Library / AndroidX ones are not deprecated.

Comment: if you can use kotlin, coroutines is a good solution

Comment: Is it safe to use androidX for lower version of android sdk ? @ianhanniballake

Comment: And I was looking for some alternative other than Loader for AsyncTask and thread handling @ianhanniballake

Comment: @Prashantverma - AndroidX supports back to API 14.